# Getting hash map result from sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I want to get a data structure like this after the sql query:-
Users table has username and city. It has 10000 records

```rb
    {
      "cities_arry": {
         "NY": ["john", "Mich", "Roh", "Dh", "Vir"],
         "KL": ["Big", "ching", "qull"],
          ...
        
     }    
    }
```

update: it is not possible to store nested hash on redis. So have to use MongoDb or some other tool.

- Suppose you have a table users and you have city and username, and you want to find a data structure like above, then how would you approach

How to get faster query result to get data structure like this.

Comment: Kindly remove the devote please

Comment: @Dear moderator, please allow this question or delete the question. Please dont decrease my hard-earned points.

Comment: Did you check the the RedisJSON module for Redis?

Comment: @GuyKorland - Sure I will check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Redis doesn't support nested data structures, and specifically it doesn't support a Hash inside a Hash :) You basically have a choice between two options: either serialize the internal Hash and store it in a Hash field or use another Hash key and just keep a reference to it in a field of the outer Hash.